# Is Dark Matter accounted for in early universe inflationary models?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, cosmological-inflation

In the early universe there must have been an abundance of dark matter unless it formed by some unknown process later on. If it were present, is this significant and factored into our models?

Comment: First the bad news (it's a pop science book), now the good news, imo anyways,  (it's by L. Krauss) and he sticks to the facts related to the above question and gives a lots of detail, it's bit dated though: http://www.amazon.com/Quintessence-Mystery-Missing-Mass-Universe/dp/0465037410/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1438940075&sr=1-2&keywords=quintessence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what caused inflation, and we don't know what dark matter is. You'll appreciate that this makes a definitive answer to your question somewhat elusive.

However it's generally believed that the matter we see around us today was created at the end of inflation by the decay of the inflaton field. This included both baryonic and dark matter, though at this point there was no distinction between them. If dark matter is supersymmetric particles then the distinction between baryonic and dark matter only emerged after the supersymmetry breaking transition. And of course we don't know when and how the supersymmtry breaking transition occurred (or even if there ever was one).

But the details don't matter that much. Models of inflation use an inflaton field without worrying about exactly what it was made from. Where dark matter does make a difference is in models of galaxy formation, because it's widely believed that dark matter was responsible for the rapid aggregation of matter that eventually led to galaxies. The density of the matter we can see is far too low to form galaxies on any realistic timescale.